# Common Lisp - Need help getting code to match sample output

Tags: common-lisp

I have a school assignment that I'm trying to figure out. We were given sample output that the program should produce but I don't understand how to reproduce the output. Basically we are supposed to insert a list into a table using an 'insert' function. 'insert' is to be defined like this:

```
insert(table name value)
```

Here is some sample input/output:

```
(setq list1 (insert nil 'name1 'value1))

((NAME1 VALUE1))

(setq list2 (insert nil 'name2 'value2))

((NAME2 VALUE2))

(setq list2 (insert list2 'name3 'value2))

((NAME2 VALUE2) (NAME3 VALUE2))
```

The last setq call has me confused.  The lists containing 'name1' and 'name2' have 'nil' as the table parameter.  The list with 'name3' has list2 as the table parameter which means to insert it to the same table that has the list containing 'name2', but how could you program the function to do this?  Does Lisp have a way of extracting symbol names from setq or something?

Answer (score 0):

`setq` just sets the variable to the value returned by function `insert`.

The result of this function is either

1) a list containing a list (if the first parameter is `nil`)

```
? (list (list 'name1 'value1))
((NAME1 VALUE1))
```

2) or a list containing a list is *appended* to an expression (if the first parameter is not `nil`):

```
? list2
((NAME2 VALUE2))
? (append list2 (list (list 'name3 'value3)))
((NAME2 VALUE2) (NAME3 VALUE3))
```

so the function could be expressed as

```
(defun insert (source name value)
  (if source
    (append source (list (list name value))) ; then branch (source is not nil)
    (list (list name value))))               ; else branch (source is nil)
```

but since `(list ...)` is the same as `(append nil (list ...))`

```
? (list (list 'a 'b))
((A B))
? (append nil (list (list 'a 'b)))
((A B))
```

you can also just say

```
(defun insert (source name value)
    (append source (list (list name value))))
```